# Using Leonardo as keyboard: add wake and sleep functions

Tags: arduino-leonardo, keyboard

I want to use a Leonardo with USB chip to emit some commands via USB port to a digital piano computer (running Windows 7) for various functions. I've gotten the Leonardo to emit page up and page down functions using a simple project I found on the web. What I need now is the following set of functions: left arrow, right arrow, F11, wake, and sleep. What I need help with is:

- where is the complete list of functions available with keyboard.press?
- are wake and sleep among those available?
- if they aren't, what header file could be modified to include them?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: google `keyboard scan codes`

Comment: Thank you, I have the needed scan codes. What I need is information about where to put them in the IDE.

Comment: you said that you are able to generate PgUp and PgDn keypresses .... you do other keypresses the same way

Comment: The functions for keyboard.press (RIGHT-ARROW) and left arrow work as expected. F11, WAKE and SLEEP  are not available or are not named that way, hence my questions about the list of available functions, or what the header file is named so that I can add to it.

Comment: names like RIGHT-ARROW and F11 are just numbers ... i would suspect that they are scan codes ... i would just use a scancode for PgDn to see if my hunch is correct

Comment: try some of these codes ... http://ts.thrustmaster.com/download/accessories/pc/hotas/software/TARGET/TARGET_SCRIPT_EDITOR_basics_v1.2_Appendix.pdf

Comment: @jsotola You were right about putting numbers directly in the keypress function. I found the name for F11, namely, KEY_F11. It also works with 0xCC as argument. However, the USB HID code for F11 is 44, and that doesn't work to toggle fullscreen with the Leonardo, so there is something else going on. The HID code for sleep is 82, but that is also used for caps lock. So, there's something else going on here. The doc you linked doesn't mention wake or sleep.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a library that can be added to compile the media and system functions for USB keyboard connection into the Leonardo, as well as other Arduino modules. It is available through 'tools','library manager'; it is HID-project by NicoHood. There is an example program called "system example" at github to test it for for wake and sleep. It works perfectly.
I expect it'll work for the other functions too.